# Values not retrieved from database when triggered with the same value twice

Tags: java, hibernate

Requirement:

- List of IDs will be available.
- There may contain same IDs multiple times in the list.
- The application is hitting the database with each ID in the list in loop

  select * from TABLE where column = ID

Code:

```
public void process(Entity1 entity1){
      if (isALogic(entity1)) {
            List<Entity2> entity2List = new ArrayList<>();  //Line# 3
            entity2List = getId(entity1);  Line #4
            buisinessLogic1(entity2List);  //Some logic to process the retrieve data
            buisinessLogic2(entity2List, entity1);  //Line 6
      }
  }

private void buisinessLogic2(List<Entity2> entity2List, Entity1 entity1) {
      for (Entity2 e : entity2List) {
          if (e.getGreetings().equalsIgnoreCase("Hello")) {
              e.setGreetings(e.getGreetings().concat("_Hi")); //Line #12
          }
          storingEntity.getEntity2List().add(e);  //Line #14
      } 
  }

@Repository
public interface Entity2Repo extends JpaRepository<Entity2, Long> {

  List<Entity2> getById(String id);  //Line #19
}
```

At line #4, the repository method is triggered (Line #19) and via hibernate, we retrieve data from the database.

Please consider at Line #6 and Line #12, we set one of the column of Entity2 in the entity2List as "`Hello_Hi`" from "`Hello`". In the database, the value is still "Hello". Please note that its not updated into database and it is stored inside an object.

Please consider the  function `process` is in loop and next time, the same `entity1` (which is retrieved in the previous loop and processed as "Hello_Hi") is sent into the function `process` via argument.

At this point, the application will again trigger the query to the database via Line #4, **but in the records of `entity2List` (which is newly created at Line #3) gets the same updated result, that is, "Hello_Hi".** But the expectation was "Hello" as nothing is updated into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an entity is already persisted, you don't need to save it for the changes to be updated in hibernate cache then into database. The `save` method is mainly used to persist a transient or detached object. So your assertion :

> nothing is updated into the database.

is wrong

When you change the properties of a persisted object, you must always consider that you cannot get the original object values anymore.